# xymatrix: make long equal signs "=" to replace the arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, diagrams, tikz-styles, xymatrix

Do people know how to make long equal signs "=" to replace the arrow in the xymatrix?

```
\begin{equation}
\xymatrix{
 a    \ar@{^{(}->}[r] \ar@{^{(}->}[d] & b\\
c   & d
}\nn
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Schematically here we want to make

b = d

c = d

in the missing arrow part of this diagram.

Comment: Did you try `\ar@{=}`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\ar@{=}[<to>]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  a \ar@{^{(}->}[r] \ar@{^{(}->}[d] & b \ar@{=}[d] \\
  c \ar@{=}[r]  & d
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the output with `tikz-cd` is much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  a \arrow[r,hook] \arrow[d,hook] & b \arrow[d,equal] \\
  c \arrow[r,equal]  & d
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! this seems perfect! +1